# Stop Highcharts plot area from adjusting

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcarts with React to create a dynamic line graph. On the graph there is a series for a vertical line which can be moved around the graph in response to some user inputs elsewhere on the page.

[image]

The problem I am having is that when the vertical line is dragged to either end of the graph, Highcharts automatically adjusts the plotting area to make space for it, resulting in the graph shifting to the left or right.

I would like to turn this off and allow enough space on either side of the graph so that no automatic adjustment of the graph is performed. I have tried setting `margin` and `spacing` parameters of the chart but they do not extend the plot area in the way I need.

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to say for sure, but I would start with setting your axis `min` and `max` values. This will establish the axis extremes regardless of the data. You can also look at `minPadding` and `maxPadding` to control how the `min` and `max` are interpreted. `margin` and `spacing` control the space *around* the plot, not the plot itself.

Comment: Thanks, that just solved the problem.